# What modern laptop is "good" for Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, ubuntu, apple

I have used Ubuntu for the last 10 years. For the past 7 years, I have been using an ASUS laptop and I want to buy a new laptop. Everyone, especially in academia, seems to have MacBooks. I like it since it is well-designed, fast, and smooth, and it is Unix-based.

My problem with Apple products is that they are produced by a HUGE and powerful company, which loves black-boxes.

> "Who would have thought a tech company wouldn't have our best interest
> at heart?"  -The Mitchells Vs. The Machines

My other option is using Ubuntu, which is *open-source*, on good hardware produced by whatever company, including Apple. But will Ubuntu be able to use all the hardware resources efficiently? Or the outcome would be the same as running Ubuntu on a 7-year-old laptop, just like now?

And please correct me if I am wrong about Apple and MacBooks.

Comment: Hi Shayan, welcome to Hardware Recs! If you just want a laptop that's well supported in Ubuntu, there are plenty of options; I'd lean towards Framework's offerings, since it seems like you value open source, reparability, and first-party Linux support. If you have other requirements besides "runs Ubuntu well", please clarify them, and we can provide more thorough advice.